# Access javascript method from another file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

The question is trivial, but I'm dumb as rock with JS, and I'd like to save myself some of the precious time I need. For some reasons, nothing happens when I call a method from a javascript file in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src = "game.js"></script>

<button onclick = "init()">Start</button>


</body>
</html>
```

And game.js:

```
function init(){

    alert("external fn clicked");

}
```

Needless to say, the alert does not appear as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: You sure the JS is loading? Did you check your JS console?

Comment: Place the script element under the button element.

Comment: It looks like the JS isn't being loaded properly... that path 'game.js' just seems wrong.

Comment: it is in the same folder, so I thought a relative path just works

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I just thought js to be too similar to Java, had an error. It's fine now

Comment: so it was a typo in your code?

Comment: yes, it was exactly it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was entirely trivial - the console *is* actually useful (`ctrl`+`shift` +`j` on Windows and Chrome). The `js` did not load properly due to a syntax error.